# Show that the boundary of each of the sets is contained in $b(A)\cup b(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the boundary of each of the sets
>   $$A\cap B,    \quad    A\setminus B,   \quad    A\cup B$$
>   is contained in $b(A)\cup b(B)$. Hint: $b(A)=A^{-}\cap (\delta(A))^{-}$.

**Case:** $A\cap B$

Since $(A∩B)^{-}\subseteq A^{-}\cap B^{-}$ , it follows that
$$\begin{align*}
b(A\cap B) &=         (A\cap B)^{-} \cap (\delta(A\cap B))^-\\\\
           &\subseteq A^{-}\cap B^{-} \cap  (\delta(A)\cup \delta(B))^{-} \\\\
           &=         A^{-} \cap B^{-} \cap  (\delta(A)^{-}\cup \delta(B)^{-})\\\\
           &=         (B^{-}\cap b(A))\cup (A^{-}\cap b(B))\\\\
           &\subseteq b(A)\cup b(B).
\end{align*}$$

How can I prove case $A\setminus B$ and $A\cup B$?

Comment: Please use `\subseteq` for $\subseteq$, `\cap` and `\cup` for $\cap$ and $\cup$, and `\overline{}` for, e.g., $\overline{A}$. [See here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: [You can see here how I have formatted your post](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/873f4222-c5ee-44d4-89d5-957469ddc04e/view-source); I encourage you to emulate it in the future.

Comment: @ZevChonoles thanks. Zev!

Answer (score 1):

Let $p \in b(A\setminus B)$, so there is a sequence $\{a_n\}\rightarrow p$ where $a_n \in A\setminus B$ and also a sequence $\{c_n\}\rightarrow p$ where $c_n\in (A \setminus B)^c=B \cup A^c$. That implies that sequence ${c_n}$ has either an infinite subsequence of elements from $A^c$ (and this yields that $p\in b(A)$) or an infinite subsequence of elements from $B$ (and this yields that $p \in b(B)$).

Using set identities one can write the following:
$$b(A \setminus B)=\overline{A\setminus B} \cap \overline{(A\setminus B)^c}=
\overline{A \cap B^c} \cap \overline{A^c \cup B}$$
One can notice that $\overline{A \cap B^c} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B^c}$ and $\overline{A^c \cup B}=\overline{A^c} \cup \overline{B}$, this implies that the last set is fully contained in 
$$\overline{A} \cap \overline{B^c} \cap (\overline{A^c} \cup \overline{B})=
(\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c} \cap \overline{B^c}) \cup
(\overline{B} \cap \overline{B^c} \cap \overline{A}) \subseteq b(A) \cup b(B)$$

The same idea one can use for $b(A \cup B)$: let $p \in b(A\cup B)$, so there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}\rightarrow p$ of elements from the $A \cup B$, this sequence has either an infinite subsequence of elements from $A$ or from $B$; together with the existence of a subsequence $\{c_n\}\rightarrow p$ from $(A\cup B)^c=A^c \cap B^c$ it proves the required inclusion.

Again, using set identities:
$$b(A \cup B)=\overline{A \cup B} \cap \overline{(A\cup B)^c}=
(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})\cap \overline{A^c \cap B^c} \subseteq 
(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})\cap (\overline{A^c} \cap \overline{B^c})=$$
$$=(\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c} \cap \overline{B^c}) \cup 
(\overline{B} \cap \overline{B^c} \cap \overline{A^c}) \subseteq b(A) \cup b(B)
$$